# DB Context query ToDictonary where values are the list of enties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use the ToDictionaryAsync method on a dbcontext but can't figure out how to designate they values for the dictionary.

Due to performance I need to pull in the main table and some of its relations and work on that set. To speed things up later on I thought a dictionary would help. I am hoping that one of you knows how to do this using Linq.

What I have now is this:

```
var entitlements = await context.DbSet //<y> // the value for the dictionary later on
    .Include(e => e.E)
    .Include(et => et.E.Et)
    .Include(eam => eam.E.Eam)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.ForeignKey, y => y);
```

My problem now is that 'y' (in the dictionary constructor) is a singular entity of 'y' and what I need is a list because the foreign key mapped to possibly many values.

I would really like to do this without populating a collection and iterating over it again.

Comment: Use ToLookup() .

Comment: As kara stated, the best way is ToLookup(). A group by works also.

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: Entity Framework Core 2.1

Comment: Can't you start the query off the entity that `y` refers to? That'll give you a natural unique grouping.

Comment: I can't. I am trying to push this data to another remote which uses the foreign key so the main purpose is to have a fast lookup on that key to help with the insert.